# Show selected out of stock products In Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, shortcode

I'm trying to find a solution to a client demand, without success. She's asking me how to show a selected number of out of stock products on her online store. By default, the Woocommerce setting is set to "hide out of stock products", but she wants to select some of her products and show them (even with 0 stock, because she wants to tell their customers that those few products will be available soon -there is a text for this-).

We have tried with a very simple snippet using the hook `woocommerce_product_is_visible` that we thought it would work, but there is something that we are missing...

This is de code:

```
// [WooCommerce] Show some out of stock products even the hide option is active
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_is_visible', 'keep_showing_specific_out_of_stock_product_list', 10, 2 );
function keep_showing_specific_out_of_stock_product_list( $visible, $product_ID ){

    $product_list = array( 18013, 18050 ); // Insert the products IDs that want to show

    return in_array( $product_ID, $product_list )? true : $visible;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you don't simply use a [Woocommerce shortcode](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#section-6) like:

1) In the Wordpress text editor of a page or a post (or in a widget):

```
[products ids="18013,18050"]
```

2) In any PHP code file:

```
echo do_shortcode( "[products ids='18013,18050']" );
```

The products out of stock are displayed just like in this real example:

[image]

Comment: First of all, I'm sorry for the mistakes in my previous post (thank you for your corrections).
And about your solution, should the shortcode to be inserted into my snippet? If so, the code is right, isn't it?
And finally, I don't know if this solution is nice for my client, but I'd try to convince her. The solution would be to create a new page, only to show "available soon" products, right?
Thank you again, @LoicTheAztec

Comment: @Rafa This solution is perfect and will keep a similar html output than in the shop. you can use it in a page, in a post, in a widget that accept shortcodes, or in any PHP code too.

Comment: ¡OH! I didn't know about this shortcode! It was so simple!!! You saved my life, @LoicTheAztec. Thank you! :D